# How to copy the coordinate (latitude/longitude) in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, copy-paste

In Google Maps on my Android, I know when I click on a place on the map, it shows lat/long in the search bar.  But how do I COPY the lat/long?

All the forums I have read seem to have old info.  They say to click on the lat/long values to copy.  But when I click on the lat/long (that is now in the search bar), it changes to the address.  Some of the old info also says to swipe up to see more data but again, that area now shows the address, not the lat/long.

Comment: As a workaround you could copy the "Plus Code" (aka "Open Location") location which contains the geo location data just like lat/lon, but in a different format. There are apps and web sites which can convert this code back to lat/lon.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but ...  I'm gathering this info to be used by a group of people that are involved in emergency preparedness.  We want to be able to send lat/long info via radio to emergency responders when the internet is down.  So we won't be able to use a website to convert.  An app would not work since not everyone would have the app installed.  Plus, I looked into converting & found code you can use in your own program, but not a website.  Plus, it says it's hard to convert when you don't have the full 8+2 but sometimes I get 4+2.

Comment: The 4+2 has to have a city or locality after it to identify which part of the world that code represents, https://github.com/google/open-location-code. If you are online you can use reverse geocoding or offline depend upon a pre-cached list of locations assuming you are just supporting one state/province/country.

Comment: Yes, the 4+2 has a city with it.  It's just too complicated to tell a group of people how to convert it to lat/long.  I have not found a website that converts it to lat/long.

Comment: If I long press a location, maps places a pin and shows information about that point including a coordinate. Clicking on the coordinate copies it to the clipboard. Does that not work for you? I also just noticed the coordinate will appear in the search box after a long press

Comment: I tried long press on a location.  The lat/long shows in the search bar & the street address shows below the map.  If I click on the lat/long, it changes to the street address so I can't copy the lat/long.  The above is when I have internet.  If I do NOT have internet, when I tap the lat/long, then I can copy.  This is a work around but I wanted to get instructions for a group of people & I'm sure someone will forget this detail.  Note that long press & tap do the same thing.

Comment: You need to long press the search bar to get into text selection mode. For some reason, that doesn't always work, zooming in first seems to help

Comment: Once the lat/long appears in the search bar, if I either tap or long press, the search bar changes to the street address. So at that point I cannot select the lat/long. You say to try to zoom in, but on what? I can zoom in on the map, but cannot zoom in on the search bar.